# Android: OnClickListener of Button on CardView

Tags: onclicklistener, android-context, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I'm a bit of a newbie so I apologize if this is an easy question.

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-cardview-example/#comment-7174

It shows how to make a few CardViews in a layout with 2 TextViews in each - all programmatically.

I would like to modify it to have a Button instead of the TextViews and to have each Button make a Toast notification upon press. I am currently stuck because I have no context to make the Toast with (because I can only access the buttons in the MyRecyclerViewAdapter class). How may I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the fact that you have access to a button, means you have acces to a context. and to my knowledge, a onclick event on a button means that the button is still alive, and then you could assume that the context for the button is still active. The way to get the context from a view is very simple:

```
view.getContext();
```

The reason i mention the assumtion is that, relying on a view's context, could be a bad idea (for example after calling a webservice or something else, where a view could have been destroyed).